# How to decide between clavinova models from different years?

Tags: instruments, digital-piano

I am looking into buying a used clavinova CLP.

A used one because I don't need all the new features and the clavinova models already had [a high quality standard in the past years](http://www.clavinova.de/allgemein/ist-ein-clavinova-etwas-fuer-anfaenger-oder-fortgeschrittene-3). So for the same money I'd need to buy a new one, I should be able to get a used one with higher quality.

Looking at the past couple of years, there are [quite some models](http://de.yamaha.com/de/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalpianos/clp_series/#list=all&mode=paging&psort=latest) that have to be considered. So the question arose:

**(How) can I compare clavinova models from different years in terms of quality?**

Do the model numbers help to find out which models are equivalent to each other?

 Is there an comparative overview over the models somewhere?

Comment: From the current product range the `CLP-585` or `CLP-575` would be great for me, and the `CLP-545` or `CLP-535` would be okay. The `CLP-525` is not in my scope. So my goal is to make a list for each of the 4 _good choices_  with all the models from the last 10 years that are   equivalent.

Comment: I finally found "my" clavinova. It is a used CLP-470 and I am so very happy with it. (The linear graded hammer technology feels wonderful realistic.) For me the approach "look for the matching models by number" worked fine.  CLP-4**7**0 ---matches---> CLP-5**7**5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### step 1) do a comparison by price

Every few years Yamaha brings out a new range of Clavinova CLP models. In this range there are always several models for different price &  quality expectations.

Models with a similar original price roughly match the same quality expectations.

Their features will vary of course, but since [after 2005 the improvements where quite small](http://www.ebay.de/gds/Yamaha-Clavinova-Geraete-von-1997-2010-/10000000019690721/g.html) it doesn't matter much if you get a certain model or its equivalent from two years ago.

**From this chart choose which models are in your scope:**

[image: Clavinova models from 2005 to 2014 compared by price]
(prices are corrected through time to account for inflation. The models from 2011 (CLP-4..) are missing in the chart because i don't have information about their original price. If you do, please let me know.)

### step 2) fine tune your choice

Got to the [yamaha model comparison site](http://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalpianos/clp_series/?mode=series#selected=225356_71982_&list=all&mode=paging).
**Select the models you found out to be in your scope and click "compare".**

Have fun finding out which models are a good match for you. :-).

Answer (score 2):

before this gets closed for being off-topic, you just look for the highest or 2nd highest middle number of any given range... 5**8**5 over 575 etc.

The first digit is the 'year' but there's no guarantee that they are always sequential, periodically the numbering style changes & I haven't followed the numbering scheme in many years.

Each year will have a larger sample-set than the previous year; which can be pretty subtle year on year, but very noticeable in a 5-year comparison.
The top model compared to bottom for each year will have a larger sample ROM & higher simultaneous note capability, apart from anything else.

Comment: Hello Tetsujin. The `first digit is the year part` is new for me. Thanks. I don't think this question is off topic. It is not a shopping recommendation request, but a general question about this e-piano brand. (As far as I know the most used brand). Do you think an approach like `the top pianos of each years are roughly the same quality` might work. One problem might be, that [Yamaha does't realease the same amount of models every time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Yamaha_products#Digital_pianos).

Comment: Looking at that list, the CVPs form an easier-to-follow line on the numbering, CLPs are harder to follow, but they have always renumbered at whim, or when one sequence reaches a logical conclusion, or just to keep you guessing;) Maybe try http://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalpianos/clp_series/?mode=series#tab=product_lineup&list=all&mode=paging&page=1

Comment: Wikipedia also is often good for simply finding the history of long-running ranges: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clavinova

Answer (score 2):

Update:  There were a few years around 2000 (not sure which) when Yamaha's sound priorities differed from mine.  However, things have been relatively straightforward with the 5X5, 6X5 and 7X5 series, as the first number represented the order of introduction and the centre number represented the position in the range.   Each generation incorporates specification upgrades at every level, but (at least as far as sound and touch are concerned) those at the lower end of the range see more nominal upgrades than those at the top end.
For example, the 525, 625 and 725 have "GH3", "GH3X" and "GHS" weightings respectively.

In terms of sound modeling, Virtual Resonance Modelling is introduced to the 635 and later the 725 (joining the higher end of the range).
In terms of available piano sounds, the 525 has CFIIIS piano but the 625 has CFX wirg binaural sampling and Bosendorfer Imperial (becoming more like the rest of the range in this regard).
There are acoustic/touch changes at the top of the range that do not show up in the specs, including better padding of the the key movements in the top end of the 7X5 series.
The power supplies at the top end of the range are now external, but I don't know if this is for acoustic reasons or just to make the individual parts lighter.
Naturally, many things have remained unchanged; for example, ounterweights have yet to trickle down from the X85 end into any of the other instruments.
Based on Yamaha's own specs, e.g. https://europe.yamaha.com/en/products/musical_instruments/pianos/clavinova/clp-775/specs.html